# Can't figure out how an old email relay is set up -- need to change passwords

Tags: sendmail

I have an old server running that is poorly documented.  At some point I changed how the email sending worked (sending cron messages and from Drupal ).  I can't figure out where the relay/password information is.  Drupal says it is using sendmail.  The mail log messages are all from sendmail and sm-mta.  None of the config files for sendmail have any custom information in them.  Postfix isn't installed.
How can I figure out how I'm sending mail?

Comment: You can search through EVERY file on your system with the terminal command `sudo find / -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -r sudo grep -l 'Custom information'`. Read `man find xargs grep sudo`.

Comment: As we don't even know what OS/release you're asking about (*we have no idea what you consider 'old' as I've worked in organizations that replaced hardware every eighteen months (18 months was considered old), others that worked on five or longer year cycles*) so your question is without actual basic clues.

Comment: Check if `/etc/mail/authinfo` file exists and contains the password.  **WARNING**: sendmail uses "compiled" version of the file.